# Компиляция Golang DLL для 32 битных систем

Tags: windows, golang, dll

В этом деле новичок. Сумел скомпилить 64 битную длл, 32 никак не выйдет, пересмотрел кучу туториалов, все не работает или я скорее всего что то не понимаю. Работаю на Win10, в VS Code.

x64 компилирую

```
go build -o release\returnHWID_x64.dll -buildmode=c-shared .
```

Пробую выставить на x32 вот этим способом

```
set CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++ GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 CGO_ENABLED=1
```

При компиляции выбивает

```
# runtime/cgo
exec: "i686-w64-mingw32-gcc": executable file not found in %PATH%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужен кросскомпилятор. Цель `c-shared` требует компилятора Си. В Вашем случае, кросскомпилятора `i686-w64-mingw32-gcc`. Установите его и всё. Проще всего установить его используя установщик [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). Если не ошибаюсь, то имя пакета `cygwin32-gcc-core`.